# Generating modal classes in laravel PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, crud

It seems like Laravel is the new hot framework in the market so I decided to build my next project on it, My database has 8 tables in it (Relational database). So one of the reasons I am trying to use laravel is that it generates the modal classes for you automatically in the modal folder with CRUD operations.

So I have my database schema ready, 
I am reading these 2 books

```
 - Getting started with laravel 4 by Raphael Saunier
 - Laravel 4 CookBook by Christopher PITT
```

Both using mysqlite as the datasource and using `artisan` to create database schema and creating modal classes.so that doesn't make sense, when I have my database mysql ready, why I am creating again it in DB?

[I have seen many links for creating modal classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470645/autogenerate-model-classes-with-laravel-4-aka-using-an-existing-database-with-l) but mostly are from `2013` so maybe not quite updated.

My question is

- Does Laravel really generates modal classes for you if the datasource is mysql with CRUD operations?- any tutorial will be helpful

Comment: downvoters please tell the reason, I did lot of research before posting.

Answer (score 2):

I hope i got your question right.

Laravel doesn't really care which database type you use as long as you [specify it correctly in your `app/config/database.php`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database)-file.

The scheme is usually created using [migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations). Those migrations are also independent when it comes to the underlying db-type. But you can also create your scheme conventionally or use an existing db (if it fits), which may require you to override the table name of your `[model][3]`-classes in some cases, among other customizations.

I don't know the books you are reading, but i can recommend laracasts [free screencast-series on laravel 4](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch) (there are also free series on laravel 5 if you want to use that). It should get you up and running.

**UPDATE**

I guess the fastest way to create models would be to use [Jeffrey Ways Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators).
Have a look at the link. Using that would require you to execute 8 commands like

```
php artisan generate:model YourModel
```

I highly recommend looking at all the other commands it provides. I personally use the `generate:resource` command very often. Jeffrey also provides a [Tutorial regarding his Generators](https://laracasts.com/lessons/fast-workflow-with-generators) on Laracasts, which is definitively worth watching. But i don't know if those generators already work with Laravel 5.

**UPDATE 2**

That command creates an Class in your models-folder, that has no body, which is fine, as it extends Eloquent, Laravels ORM (Active Record). This model should work out of the box, if the Name of the Model corresonds to the name of the Model class.

*An Example*

Given the following table

```
CREATE TABLE products(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP
)
```

The Model

```
public class Product extends Eloquent {
}
```

would work, because Elouent automatically Maps the Table Attributes.

Doing things like

```
$products = Product::all();
$productOne = Product::find(1);
$newProduct = new Product;
$newProduct->name = "my new product";
$newProduct->save();
// and so on
```

Are working right away (Be aware that laravel expects you to have the two timestamp-columns defined in you model-tables. If you wish to disable this, edit your model by adding `public $timestamps = false;`).

Comment: but that still doesn't answers my concern, if I have a database with 8 tables , how I can generate 8 model files fastly ,(ofcourse without writing the code)

Comment: @SmartMindx see my update. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @nozzleman doing php artisan generate:model YourModel will just create YourModel.php in models folder without any code in it, it will just create a class.

Comment: @SmartMindx thats right. and this class extends eloquent right? This enables you to du your CRUD operations on the model (eg. `YourModel::all()` etc.). Thats one of the big benefits from Laravel. You dont need to write that code, as it gets mapped from the database automatically. The only code you would have to write would be customization (table name, validation etc.) Laravel is heavily based on **Convention over Configuration**

Comment: @nozzleman we haven't mentioned the column names in our class product, are you sure it will get mapped, I think there is something called fillable where we have to mention these column names.

Comment: i suppose it is the best to simply try it out. `$fillable` is only relevant for mass-assignment (see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment), which goes sth. like `Product::create(['name' => 'My Product']`. It is all explained very good in the linked laracast-series, which i can not recommend enough. Yes, im pretty sure, as i never declare any members (except overriding Eloquent-members) im my models, and they work.

Answer (score 0):

php artisan make:model YourModelName